# What is wrong with this proof by induction?

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

Can someone identify the problem with this proof?

Let $p$ be a polynomial of positive degree $n$ such that $p$ is a product of degree one polynomials and p(0)= 0. If $c \in \mathbb R$ satisfies $p(c) = 0$ then $ c = 0$.

It is a proof with induction on n of a polynomial p.

[image: Click here to see proof:]

Comment: Hint: the induction step assumes that the degree of $q$ is $\ge 3$. But you haven't proved the $n=2$ case.

Comment: If $p(x) = x(x-1)$ we see that $p(1) = 0$ but clearly $1 \neq 0$.